# javascript regex for comma separated number duplicates

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to check for duplicates in a string of numbers separated by commas:

```
var rgx = /* the regex here? */ 
var str = "1,2,3,4,4,5";
var valid = rgx.test(str);
```

if it detects that there are duplicates, like in this case there is a duplicate of, I need valid to return false.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex,

```
/\b(\d+)\b.*?,\1\b/.test(str);
```

It returns true if the string contains duplicate number.

**Example:**

```
> var str = "1,2,3,4,4,5";
undefined
> /\b(\d+)\b.*?,\1\b/.test(str);
true
> var str = "1,2,3,4,5";
undefined
> /\b(\d+)\b.*?,\1\b/.test(str);
false
```

If you want it to return false for a string which contains duplicate number then put the whole regex inside a negative lookahead.

```
> var str = "1,2,3,4,4,5";
undefined
> /^(?!.*?\b(\d+)\b.*?,\1\b)/.test(str);
false
> var str = "1,2,3,4,5";
undefined
> /^(?!.*?\b(\d+)\b.*?,\1\b)/.test(str);
true
```

Comment: I tried the regex for this "1,2,2,3" and it returned as valid

Comment: @swaggyP yep, the first part of my regex would return true if the input contains any duplicate number and the second part of my answer would return false if the string contains any duplicate number.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense: Also how would I check to see if the string contains only numbers separated by commas

Comment: try `^\d+(?:,\d+)+$` this won't match a single number. To match also the single number, change the last `+` to `*`

Comment: example would be better.